# How to prevent download action to execute multiple times with a html link element?

Tags: html, css

Is there a simple way with pure CSS/HTML for example to prevent a download from happening multiple times when using the HTML link element with the download attribute?

At the moment there is no indication or a way to disable to button easily while the download is busy.
If it are big files it sometimes takes a while for the user to see the download starting, which results into clicking on the download link multiple times.

```
<a href="http://download.com" download/>
```

Comment: why don't you want to use javascript?

Comment: Does this mean you want it to be active again when the download is finished? Why?